# Where are my sshd logs?

Tags: arch-linux, logs, openssh, sshd

I can't find my sshd logs in the standard places.

What I've tried:

- Not in `/var/log/auth.log`
- Not in `/var/log/secure`
- Did a system search for `'auth.log'` and found nothing
- I've set `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to explicitly use `SyslogFacility AUTH` and `LogLevel INFO` and restarted sshd and still can't find them.

I'm using OpenSSH 6.5p1-2 on Arch Linux.

Comment: I could not find logs in the journalctl but found them in /var/log/auth.log thanks to your question. <insert funny face here>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found the output of sshd and other core services in 'journalctl'.

See more at the Arch Wiki entry for systemd:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Journal

Answer (score 82):

Try this command to view the log from systemctl:

```
journalctl -u sshd | tail -n 100
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, but `journalctl _COMM=sshd` does.

Comment: Ah, yes - systemctl being completely consistent and predictable as usual.

Comment: You can use the `-f` option to follow the log: `journalctl -fu sshd`

Comment: wingedsubmariner - I know it's been almost 4 years, but... do you remember what distro you were on at the time? I suspect the unit file on your distro was called "openssh" or just "ssh" rather than "sshd". The thing with the systemd project is they consider distros to be their users, and distros are free to use whatever names they want for unit files (like Debian calls apache's webserver `apache2` while RedHat calls it `httpd`).

Comment: `journalctl -t sshd -e`

Comment: On my Raspberry Pi, the service was called ssh.service, so the command is:
`journalctl -u ssh.service`

Answer (score 43):

A better way to see the last part of the log is:

```
journalctl -u sshd -n 100
```

Using `tail` on the output of `journalctl` can be very slow. It took 5 minutes on a machine where I tried it, while the above command returns instantly.

Comment: And you don't lose line coloring! Should be top solution imo

Answer (score 22):

You should be able to filter messages from `sshd` using:

```
journalctl -u ssh
```

or (depending on your distribution)

```
journalctl -u sshd
```

which will show logs in a `less` style format (you can search `/`, navigate via PgUp, PgDown etc.).

- `-e` brings you to the end of logs.
- `-u` parameter filters through meta field `_SYSTEMD_UNIT` which is (at least on Debian) set to `ssh.service`, thus `sshd` won't match.
- `-f` follows logs in real-time
- `-n 100` displays given number of lines (useful with `-f`)

Alternatively you can use meta-fields filtering:

```
journalctl _COMM=sshd
```

You can display whole journal record with all meta-fields by exporting to JSON:

```
journalctl -u ssh -o json-pretty
```

that would give you something like:

```
    ...
    "_PID" : "7373",
    "_COMM" : "sshd",
    "_EXE" : "/usr/sbin/sshd",
    "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/system.slice/ssh.service",
    "_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "ssh.service",
    ...
```

In case you wonder how to display only kernel messages:

```
journalctl -k -f
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation for this strange syntax (`journalctl _COMM=sshd`)?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni `-u` filters through metadata field `_SYSTEMD_UNIT` which is on Debian set to `ssh.service`. All params starting with underscore are accessing metafiels. In similar manner you can filter via `_PID` or `_TRANSPORT`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your syslog configuration. Most probalby `/etc/syslog.conf` or `/etc/rsyslog.conf`   You should look for lines with `auth` for example in my config:

`auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log`

`*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog`

Comment: Neither of those files exists. I believe those files are created by syslog-ng whereas Arch has replaced that with systemd

Comment: In Scientific Linux authpriv.* point to `authpriv.*                                            /var/log/secure` inside the file  `/etc/rsyslog.conf`