# Cannot log in if shell is set to /usr/bin/bash

Tags: arch-linux, login

So I just ran into an interesting issue. On Arch Linux, if I create a user that uses a shell from `/usr/bin` they cannot log in. I create the user with:

`useradd -m -G wheel -s /usr/bin/bash username`

and when they try to log in, they get 'Login Incorrect'. But if I edit `/etc/passwd` and change the shell to `/bin/bash`, everything works fine.

Any ideas what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Is there an executable called `bash` in `/usr/bin`? Is this also listed in the list of valid login shells (`/etc/shells`)?

Comment: Also, check the logs. On Debian/Ubuntu, the authentication stuff goes to `/var/log/auth.log` and any messages from PAM modules should be there, too. On Arch, they might be somewhere else, or perhaps you'll just have to go through `journalctl`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114189/where-are-my-sshd-logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Arch Wiki makes clear](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups):

> Warning: In order to be able to log in, the login shell must be one of
>   those listed in /etc/shells, otherwise the PAM module pam_shell will
>   deny the login request. **In particular, do not use the /usr/bin/bash
>   path instead of /bin/bash**, unless it is properly configured in
>   /etc/shells.

```
cat /etc/shells                         
#
# /etc/shells
#

/bin/sh
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Truthfully, I completely forgot that `/etc/shells` existed. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

If `bash` is in `/bin/bash` and `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are not linked together, then the login program cannot start the shell if you specify a wrong path to Bash.

If the binares are linked together, then you need to edit `/etc/shells` to include both variants.

Comment: The binaries are installed to /usr/bin and are linked to /bin