# What kind of network information can be gathered via journald by default?

Tags: linux, networking, logs, systemd-journald

I'm looking for info like TCP/ACK request, session opened, errors, refused connections etc..

Answer (score 0):

So, I concluded that there is nothing much you can see by default. Best I could do is specifically set up logging, check iptables as it suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/600003/monitor-bandwidth-usage-per-user-in-linux), or filter like it recommended [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114189/where-are-my-sshd-logs)