# no way to see log from sshd

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, logs

I've already tried to follow the solutions from [Where are my sshd logs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114189/where-are-my-sshd-logs), in particular I have:

- changed `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by setting `SyslogFacility` to `AUTH` or `AUTHPRIV` and
  `LogLevel` to `VERBOSE` or even `DEBUG`
- checked `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, it contains

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
```

- restarted sshd by either `service ssh restart` or by `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` or even by manually killing `sshd` and then restarting it
- to test the logging I ssh from another machine and give first a wrong password, and next the good one.
- to check the logs I've tried all the following:

```
cat /var/log/auth.log
cat /var/log/debug
cat /var/log/messages
cat /var/log/daemon.log
cat /var/log/syslog
journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service
journalctl _COMM=ssh
journalctl _COMM=sshd
journalctl -u ssh
journalctl -u sshd
```

but there's no message at all from sshd. What else remains to show some log from sshd?

Comment: You declared `/var/log/syslog` but not listed in the checked list

Comment: forgot it, now added. Practically I did check all the files by `grep ssh /var/log/*`

Comment: Is the `-` is intentional in your log conf ? `-/var/log/syslog`

Comment: it's the default, and I don't see how duplicate logging of auth or authpriv could help